# Отправка файла на jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Такой вопрос: нужно отправить фото на этот адрес: https://s.taobao.com/image
и получить ответь типа:

```
{
    status: 1,
    error: false,
    name: "TB1hYvjLFXXXXa4XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    status: 1,
    url: "//g-search3.alicdn.com/img/bao/uploaded/i4/TB1hYvjLFXXXXa4XXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делаю так:

```
<form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h1 class="header">Выберите фотографию</h1>
    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('imgFile').click(); return false;" id="btnUpload"></a>
    <a href="#" id="btnSearch"></a>
    <input id="imgFile" name="imgFile" type="file">
</form>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#imgFile').live('change', function () {
        ext=$(this).val();
        if(!ext.match(/.jpg|.jpeg|.png$/)) {
            alert("Допустимые форматы файлов: .jpg или .png");
            return;
        }
        var formData = new FormData($('#upload_form')[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://s.taobao.com/image',  //Server script to process data
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h1 class="header">Выберите фотографию</h1>
    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('imgFile').click(); return false;" id="btnUpload"></a>
    <a href="#" id="btnSearch"></a>
    <input id="imgFile" name="imgFile" type="file">
</form>
```

но получаю ошибку, в чем может быть причина?

Comment: Какую ошибку вы получаете?

Comment: Выполните код и подождите не много.

Comment: Где кнопка submit?

Comment: при выборе картинки фото сразу отправится на сервер, ошибка такая: {"status":0,"error":true,"errorCode":"509","errorMsg":"请重新上传试试","extraInfo":""}

Comment: А если руками отправить с ресурса все ок?

Comment: Да конечно вот пробуйте: taobao.com только нужно с начало поменять страну на китай у world.taobao.com нет поиск по фото

Comment: Поставьте Fiddler  и посмотрите как скомпонован запрос, и чем отличается Ваш ajax. Там категорию товара не надо указать в дополнение к картинке?

Comment: нет, там просто открываешь фото и дальше переадресует на результаты. Fiddler-ом не умею пользоваться (

Comment: @mega94 Это не намного сложнее, чем написать вопрос на StackOverflow :) https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler.

Comment: Не очень понимаю, зачем нужен fiddler, если уже есть консоль разработчика, и запрос в ней виден. Советую посмотреть на набор заголовков. Эксперементировать можно curl'ом (для этого можно 'copy as curl' на запросе во вкладке Network), ну или $.ajax.

Comment: заголовков сайта вы имеете ввиду?

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать AJAX:

```
$('#upload').on('click', function() {
    var file_data = $('#sortpicture').prop('files')[0];   
    var form_data = new FormData();                  
    form_data.append('file', file_data);
    alert(form_data);                             
    $.ajax({
                url: 'upload.php', // имя серврного PHP скрипта
                dataType: 'text',  // формат ответа сервера
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form_data,                         
                type: 'post',
                success: function(php_script_response){
                    alert(php_script_response); // выводим результат на экран                    }
     });
});
```

только формат ответа поменять на JSON

Серверная часть:

```
<?php

    if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'] ) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
    }
    else {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name']);
    }

    // тут код для формирования ответа JSON

?>
```